# How do we build an API using fastAPI that just triggers another Python file executing a query, without waiting for it's response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, asynchronous, fastapi

This is my current code that waits for the response. details is basically the file imported whose get_query_status method is being called.

```
@app.get("/trigger_query")
def trigger_query(database:str, entity_name, token: str = Depends(oath2_scheme)):
    value = details.get_query_status(database, entity_name)
    if value is None:
        return HTTPException(status_code= 404, detail= value[1])
    return {'status_code': 200, 'detail': value}
```

I understand how we can create APIs using fastAPIs, but it always returns success once the query execution is complete.

What would be the way to approach without waiting for it's response? A code demonstration would be helpful.

Comment: You could have the code run on another endpoint, and just send a request to it from that one

Comment: But I dont want to wait for response @Peter

Comment: It depends on how much overhead you want in your project and what you are trying to do. If its more complicated I would recommend a setup with celery. You can use celery to run expensive long running task in a task queue.

Comment: @LearnerJS You don't need to wait for a response though. You just use `requests.get` or `requests.post` from one endpoint to trigger the other.

Comment: `request.get` or `request.post` will block until there is a response. Even if the endpoint is on itself non-blocking, the http status has to travel back and be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple solution without celery you can use background tasks.

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

def trigger_query_wrapper(database, entity_name):
    value = details.get_query_status(database, entity_name)
    # add logic for doing something with the value


@app.get("/trigger_query")
async def trigger_query(database:str, entity_name,  background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, token: str = Depends(oath2_scheme)):
    background_tasks.add_task(trigger_query_wrapper,database, entity_name)
    return {"message": "Task triggered in the background"}
```

See the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) for more details

Comment: This will create a "thread" keeping track of the status, right? could run out of memory if you have too manu calls without caution.